# Fire JS on page load and on mouse over?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have the below JS that animates an H1 I have on my page. It works fine when I use `onmouseover` instead of `onload`, but I want this to fire on BOTH page load + mouse over. How can I adjust the code to account for both of these scenarios? I can't even get it to work only on page load.

```
window.onload = function(){

  const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

  document.querySelector("h1").onload = event => {
    let iterations = 0;

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      event.target.innerText = event.target.innerText.split("")
      .map((letter, index) => {
        if(index < iterations){
          return event.target.dataset.value[index];
        }
        return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)]
      })
      .join("");

      if(iterations >= event.target.dataset.value.length) clearInterval(interval);

      iterations += 1 / 3;
    }, 30);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I have edited my code per the recommendations. Instead of calling event.target now, I have put my query selector inside variable: `name` and am using that in my function. However, I'm getting an error at the `name.innerText.split("")` line. Am I incorrectly referencing this element now?

```
window.onload = function(){

  const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  const name = document.querySelector("h1");
  name.addEventListener('mouseover', animate);
}

  function animate(){
    let iterations = 0;

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      name.innerText = name.innerText.split("")
      .map((letter, index) => {
        if(index < iterations){
          return name.dataset.value[index];
        }
        return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)]
      })
      .join("");

      if(iterations >= name.dataset.value.length) clearInterval(interval);

      iterations += 1 / 3;
    }, 30);
  }
```

Comment: You can't reference the `name` variable from `window.onLoad` in the function `animate` move `const name = document.querySelector("h1")` into the `animate function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your read about window.onload [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event), they said:

`The load event is fired when the whole page has loaded, including all dependent resources such as stylesheets, scripts, iframes, and images.`

that's mean you don't have to wait the h1 element to load it's already loaded and checked while the function inside window.load is excuted, so
you just need to add a mouseover event listener to the element, here's an ideas:

you can keep your code like this but replace the event:

```
document.querySelector("h1").onmouseover = event =>
```

or you can add event listners if you want to add a mouseenter event as example:

```
const element = document.querySelector("h1");
element.addEventListener('mouseover', onEventTrigger);
element.addEventListener('mouseenter', onEventTrigger);
```

and add this function:

```
function onEventTrigger() {
    // your logic that was inside onload
}
```

**Edit after your Edit:**

you are facing this error because the name variable not scoped inside the function animate(), you can fix it by passing the name as a parameter to the function:

```
name.addEventListener('mouseover', animate(name));
```

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my code per your recommendation but am now having trouble referencing my h1 element. I have updated my code that outlines what I have done and where the error is at - any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of set it as event, invoke it as a custom function:

```
window.onload = function() {
  const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

  document.onload = customFunction();
}

function customFunction() {
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however this is producing errors now related to my event.target.innerText portion. I guess because it's no longer an event and now lives in a function? How could I adjust that code to no longer reference the event?

Comment: @mickdeez I know. Now that you can fire the function at onload you must fix your code inside the `customFunction`